# Is "behind" the correct use

Tags: word-usage

When I spell my name, I usually say it's "Marie" with "ke" behind it. (My name is Marieke, I'm from Holland). Is this correct? I just think of it as the first letter of a word is in front so the following letters are "behind", however my husband disagrees. I could well be wrong as English is not my first language. Can you help?

Comment: If it works, and they spell it correctly after these instructions, then you are doing it correctly. There's no right or wrong way to tell someone how to spell your name, just effective or ineffective ways.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about English language or usage.

Comment: It certainly is about English language and usage. 
In English one usually says _after_ when referring to spelling letters out. _Behind `X`_ is reserved for referring to `X`'s that have a front and a back (_behind the painting_), or which are blocking one's view (_behind the tree_), or both or either (_behind the house_). This is at least two-dimensional, while letters in a row are one-dimensional and use a motion metaphor, so _after_ is preferred.

Comment: _after_ or _at the end_.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer ***followed by*** rather than ***behind***:

> It's **Marie** followed by **K** **E**.

The suggestion by outrightmental of ***then*** is reasonable, but there's a chance that ***then*** might be misheard as ***enn*** (i.e. the letter **N**).

Answer (score 1):

*Behind* is about visibility. In your case, use *followed by ke* or *ke at the end* would be better.

Answer (score 0):

From a native Chicagoan living in Brooklyn, NY, I recommend addressing an English speaker with:

> It starts with Marie, **M - A - R - I - E** *then* **K- E**.

Note how I used the word *"then"* in my delivery.  So you can rely on the listener to know how to spell "Marie" as you mention in your question.  Nice name, btw!

Answer (score 0):

I would say, "My name is Marieke.  It is spelled like Marie and then a K and E at the end."

I am assuming two things.  That in your culture the name Marie is common and it is pretty much always spelled M A R I E (and it is pronounced the same).  And that you give them your full name first so that they have context.